# With Nuxt's auto import of components, how to use the <component> element?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

Components are automatically imported since [Nuxt.js v2.13](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/directory-structure/components/).

But how can we use `<component :is="MyComponent" />`?

Written this way it throws an error:

> MyComponent is not defined

In such case, should we import components the regular way ( for example `import MyComponent from '@/components/MyComponent'`) and if so, won't the component be imported twice?

EDIT:

Script:

```js
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      componentNames: {
        index: 'ButtonSection',
        large_banner: 'LargeBanner',
        small_banner: 'SmallBanner'
      }
    }
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapState({
      sections: state => state.sections.section_list ?? null
    })
  }
}
</script>
```

Template:

```html
<template v-if="sections">
  <component
    :is="componentNames[sections[i].section_type]"
    v-for="(section, i) in sections"
    :key="i"
  />
</template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use the binding sign `:` the template sees for a defined property inside your component instance, if you don't provide that sign the attribute value as token as string, if you're adding this config :

```
export default {
  components: true
}
```

the component is resolved automatically and you could use it like :

```
<component is="ComponentName" />
```

or with raw string binding :

```
<component :is="'ComponentName'" />
```

or with property binding :

```
<component :is="MyComponent" />

...

data(){
   return{
   MyComponent:'ComponentName'
 }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure we can use `<component is="" />` without `:`? When I do so I get an error "Expected '<component>' elements to have 'v-bind:is' attribute". Also in my example, "MyComponent" is the actual name of the component I'm trying to use.

Comment: the `:` exoects that `MyComponent` to be defined in the script properties, or you could do `:is="'MyComponent'"`

Comment: Works now, thanks a lot :)
One thing: in my script, `MyComponent` is actually stored in a variable. If I do `<component :is="'variable'">` obviously it doesn't work because ``variable`` is taken as a string and JS doesn't understand that I want the content of `variable`. You see what I mean? How could I make it work in this case? To be specific, in my script it's not simply `variable` but this: `componentNames[sections[i].section_type]` <- this contains the name of the component I want to programmatically use.

Comment: you're welcome, please share the whole code to see what's going wrong

Comment: No pb, I edited the question and added the whole code

Comment: so what's the issue, the code above looks working

Comment: Sorry brother you're right, it does work now. Not sure what happened. Thanks again!

Comment: components: true does work but throws a warning for me tho. 'Expected Object, got Boolean'

Comment: this property is added to the `nuxt.config.js`